# No touches after adding touchscreen driver to CE 6 in platform builder

Tags: windows-ce, device-driver, touchscreen

I have added a TSHARC touchscreen driver to my Windows CE project, but the touch does not work.  The dll is there, as is the touchscreen calibration executable.  I have no visibility into which drivers are loaded and when.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to have to do some debugging, and touchscreen drivers tend to be challenging because they get loaded into GWES and because the electrical characteristics of touchpanels change dramatically based on size and manufacturer.  It's very rare for a driver to just work right out of the box - you almost always have to adjust sample timings and the like based on panel characteristics, and that's best done using an oscilloscope.

Things to check:

1. Is the driver getting loaded at all?  A RETAILMSG/DEBUGMSG would tell you that
2. Are you getting touch interrupts?
3. After a down interrupt, is your code getting back to state to receive an up?
4. If you look at the timings from panel signals themselves, are you sampling when the signals are stable (i.e. you're not sampling too soon after the interrupt)?

Comment: It has been a while.  Turns out it was conflicting USB drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a conflict between the OHCI driver and another USB driver already installed.